# How can I open jupyter notebooks with Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

When I open Anaconda, and open jupyter notebook, it just tells me to open it using a path directory or copy/paste an url into my browser. Is it supposed to be like that? I was expecting it would open a regular window...
Besides, it is difficult to copy and paste from the command prompt without copying the whole text in the entire window and then pasting into notepad and then selecting the url that I want. Any tips how I should most easily use jupyter notebooks? kaggle? ibm cloud? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using  the [Jupyter Qt console](https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter is designed to open in your browser as localhost.

Here is the URL you should copy (it doesn't change): http://localhost:8888/tree

I recommend to use Spyder rather than Jupyter if you are beginner, it opens window for itself as it has the option to show snippets of your code (can be allowed from options).

- Kaggle is a community to search for a proper dataset that you want to work on with your model.